# How to normalize the vertices array in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, vertex

I am trying to draw a triangle on my OpenGL window.

What I want is that I specify three points and OpenGL draws the triangle based on that, the problem is, for that I have to convert the OpenGL coordinates to normalized screen coordinates.

It would look something like this, after normalized:--

[image: Normalized OpenGL triangle]

Here the three **( X, Y )s** (*points of triangle*) will be specified by the user using three vectors.

But the problem is that the vertices(red points shown in the example figure) are in perspective or default OpenGL coordinates, but I want to make a 2D triangle, so I would not require 3D coordinates for drawing it.

Can you show me a way to convert the **vertices** into normalized coordinates (from **0.0 to 1.0 or -1.0, in both axis** to **0.0 to** *"width or height of the screen respective to the axis"***, in both axis)**

The code of the shaders(for the triangle):-

::Vertex Shader::

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
}
```

::Fragment Shader::

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}
```

What the vertices array looks like(**Sample Code**):-

```
GLfloat x = 0;   // First X Point
GLfloat y = 0;   // First Y Point

GLfloat x1 = 10; // Second X Point
GLfloat y1 = 10; // Second Y Point

GLfloat x2 = 0;  // Third X Point
GLfloat y2 = 10; // Third Y Point

GLfloat vertices[] =
{
    2 * x  / WIDTH - 1, 2 * y  / HEIGHT - 1, 0.0f, // Left
    2 * x1 / WIDTH - 1, 2 * y1 / HEIGHT - 1, 0.0f, // Right
    2 * x2 / WIDTH - 1, 2 * y2 / HEIGHT - 1, 0.0f  // Top
};
```

Comment: You mean `x* = 2 * x / screenWidth - 1`?

Comment: Read a good tutorial about "projection" and "normalized device coordinates (NDC)". It's a matter of using maths with the proper matrices.

Comment: @Ripi2 But where! It is very hard to find such '_tutorials_' for **modern** OpenGL or you just have to buy a book which rarely describes my problem above.

Comment: @NicoSchertler The triangle disappears after I put your snippet in the vertex array.

Comment: @Rabbid76 It is taken from the original code, which I am using as a sample to draw triangles on the screen.

Comment: To name three: [tut 1](https://learnopengl.com/), [tut 2](https://open.gl/), [tut 3](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/). Pay attention to "transformations" chapters.

Comment: @Ripi2 But the transformations don't say how to do it **on** the vertex array. It is done after the vertex array is defined and the projection matrix is used.

Comment: The coordinates that the vertex shader (VS) outputs must be in NDC space. If you transform them before sending data to GPU (i.e. done with CPU) or let the VS does it, it's your choice. And yes, the tuts say a lot about transformations. Read them slowly, don't try to assimilate them too quickly.